# google tango / opencv android camera app crashes/hangs

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-camera, google-project-tango

I am developing a prototype app, utilizing the tango depth camera for template matching. So far, I have been able to solve all problems with the help of already answered questions, documentation etc.

However, now I seem to have come to a stop. Last major change I made, was to draw a contour on the camera preview image, before displaying it. No matter what I do now, the app works for a while, before it crashes.

I have looked at heap dumps and allocation tracking in Android Studio. The only possibly weird thing there is that there can be a lot of memory on FinalizerReference objects in the heap dump...

I also tried moving the processing to an AsyncTask, and just skip every color frame until the task was done (so that only one task was running at a time) and the processed frame was displayed, but the problem remained.

I am using Google Tango for getting color and depth camera data and opencv in java for analyzing the data and doing the template matching.

Does someone have a clue of what these logcat messages mean?

Logcat errors:

> E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/10173/oom_score_adj; errno=2
>   E/mm-camera-isp2: abf40_trigger_update:587 aec_ratio.ratio = 0.039062
>   W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service 
>   com.lenovo.lsf.device/com.lenovo.lsf.push.service.PushService in 68068ms
>   W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.qualcomm.qti.modemtestmode/.MbnSystemService in 88020ms
>   E/InputDispatcher: channel '478a66c com.android.documentsui/com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>   E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/10113/oom_score_adj; errno=22
>   E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 76)
>   E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/32408/oom_score_adj; errno=22
>   E/InputDispatcher: channel '85c4188 com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>   E/mm-camera-isp2: abf40_trigger_update:587 aec_ratio.ratio = 0.000000
>   E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=332, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
>   E/mm-camera: mct_util_timer_handler:Error Backend stuck during HAL Command Raising SIGABRT
>   E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 76)
>   E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/32437/oom_score_adj; errno=22
>   E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 308)
>   E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 76)
>   E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/32437/oom_score_adj; errno=22
>   E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 76)
>   E/mm-camera: mct_util_timer_handler:Error Backend stuck during HAL Command Raising SIGABRT  E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
>   E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
>   E/mm-camera: cpp_module_send_buf_divert_event:545] buffer event received with no divert config
>   E/mm-camera: cpp_module_send_buf_divert_event:545] buffer event received with no divert config
>   E/Camera3-OutputStream: getBufferLocked: Stream 0: Can't dequeue next output buffer: Broken pipe (-32)
>   E/Camera3-OutputStream: returnBufferCheckedLocked: Stream 0: Error queueing buffer to native window: Broken pipe (-32)
>   E/Camera3-Device: RequestThread: Can't get output buffer, skipping request: Broken pipe (-32)
>   E/Camera3-Device: Can't return buffer to its stream: Broken pipe (-32)
>   E/Camera3-OutputStream: getBufferLocked: Stream 0: Can't dequeue next output buffer: Broken pipe (-32)
>   E/Camera3-Device: RequestThread: Can't get output buffer, skipping request: Broken pipe (-32)

Code for displaying camera preview:

```
mTango.experimentalConnectOnFrameListener(TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR, new Tango.OnFrameAvailableListener() {
    byte[] imageByteArray = new byte[colorCameraIntrinsics.height * colorCameraIntrinsics.width * 3 / 2];  
    Mat yuvMat = new Mat( colorCameraIntrinsics.height + colorCameraIntrinsics.height/2, colorCameraIntrinsics.width, CvType.CV_8UC1 );
    Bitmap bitmapDisplay = Bitmap.createBitmap( colorCameraIntrinsics.width, colorCameraIntrinsics.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
    Mat colorMatDisplay;

    @Override
    public void onFrameAvailable(TangoImageBuffer imageBuffer, int cameraId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onFrameAvailable: color frame available");
        if (colorFrameCounter < 3) { //only use every 3rd frame
            Log.d(TAG, "onFrameAvailable: skipping frame " + colorFrameCounter);
            colorFrameCounter++;
        } else {
            colorFrameCounter = 0;
            if (!stopCameraView.get()) { // Only view frame if camera view is not stopped

                // convert image buffer data to byte array
                imageBuffer.data.get(imageByteArray);

                // byte array to Mat object with YUV coding (NV21)
                yuvMat.put(0, 0, imageByteArray);

                // locking access to lastColorFrameMat
                synchronized (lockVar) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFrameAvailable: converting to bitmap");
                    // convert from YUV (NV21) Mat to RGBA Mat and place in lastColorFrameMat (global)
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(yuvMat, lastColorFrameMat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4);
                    colorMatDisplay = lastColorFrameMat.clone();
                }

                if (templateContours != null) {
                    Imgproc.drawContours(colorMatDisplay, templateContours, templateContourMaxIdx, new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255), 5);
                }

                // convert colorMatDisplay to bitmap, for display in imageview
                Utils.matToBitmap(colorMatDisplay, bitmapDisplay);

                Log.d(TAG, "onFrameAvailable: view lastColorFrameMat on phone display");

                // View colorImage in imageViewer on UI thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        imageViewer.setImageBitmap(bitmapDisplay);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things potentially happened here:

1. the buffer for camera image went out of scope.

With current Tango's SDK, the callee of `onFrameAvailable` callback only have control to `imageBuffer` within the scope of the callback. That means if you reference `imageBuffer` in an `AsynTask`, you could potentially get a null buffer, and result in a crash. The way Tango solve it is to always deep copy out the data from the callback, and process it in another thread.

2. the process is blocking Tango's thread for too long.

Without the AsyncTask, what's likely happened is that the processing blocked Tango's thread for too long, and this is know to be bad for Tango as well.